# How should I use my app.js file with AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I am looking at [Build huge apps link](http://briantford.com/blog/huuuuuge-angular-apps.html) It states:

Define and configure all modules in app.js:

```
angular.module('yourAppName', ['yourAppDep']);
angular.module('yourAppDep');
```

Define controllers, services, etc. on modules like this:

```
angular.module('yourAppDep').controller('MyCtrl', function () {
// ...
});
```

Can someone explain to me what happens with those two define lines in the app.js. Should those lines not define modules and assign them to variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume, second line should be:

```
angular.module('yourAppDep',[/* dependencies of yourAppDep*/]);
```

Thats defining `yourAppDep` module. I am also doing like that: in some top-level .js file define all modules I am using (e.g. myApp that depends on myApp.directivies, myApp.servicies, myApp.someFunctionality1, myApp.someFunctionality2) and then use `angular.module('myApp.directivies')` to fetch defined module.

This gives:

- More granularity of your code: you explicitly specify dependencies
- You see all dependencies in one file, you have nicer picture
- In tests you can mock only things you really use, but know bootstrap whole app each test.

So the main idea is: in app.js define modules and its dependenices, in other .js files implement them.

Comment: Is it easier to assign that module to a global variable such as var finance = angular.module('finance', ['finance.services']) so that then you can use that variable and add controllers and filters to it?

Comment: @Anne the trouble is that it _does_ create a global variable (!) which we can completely avoid by using `angular.module` calls.

Comment: @Valentyn Shybanov - One more question. Can you explain what you mean by "angular.module('myApp.directivies') to fetch defined module"

Comment: @pkozlowski.opensource - thanks for your advice. Are you saying it's not a good idea to create that global variable. It seemed to be easier to me when I saw the controllers defined and saw they were defined just after a short variable name.

Comment: angular.module do two things: when it has two arguments, it creates new module, but when you call it with one argument you'll get previously created module. This way you can avoid poluting global scope with global variables.